# How can I return promise while migrating to Cucumber 4?

Tags: javascript, protractor, cucumberjs

I am migrating the test cases to cucumber 4, I have following snippet which I want to convert in cucumber 4 type of code.

homePage.js

```
this.isHomeButtonEnabled = function(){
  var isButtonEnabled = true;
   browser.element(by.css('.home-btn')).getAttribute('disabled').then(function () {
         isButtonEnabled = false;
   })
   return isButtonEnabled;
}
```

And my expectation scenario is,

```
expect(homePage.isHomeButtonEnabled()).to.be(true);
```

Now I above function i.e `isHomeButtonEnabled` should return promise. But what is the appropriate way to migrate above snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1)** use protractor `isEnabled()` api:

```
this.isHomeButtonEnabled = function(){
   return element(by.css('.home-btn')).isEnabled();
}
```

**Option 2)** use `getAttribute('disabled')`:

```
this.isHomeButtonEnabled = function(){
   return element(by.css('.home-btn')).getAttribute('disabled')
         .then(function(disabled){
             return disabled === null ? true: false;
          });
}
```